# Set default resolution in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, resolution, reset

How does one set the default resolution in Lubuntu 12.04. I set it using both `Arandr` and the default resolution setter. Both times would reset after a reboot. How do I permanently set the resolution.

Note: I am doing this as an unprivileged user. Should I do it on my admin account?

Answer (score -2):

The solution in [this page](http://anhe51.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/change-resolution-of-unknown-monitor-in-ubuntu-11-10/) should work for you. At the bottom it shows you how to make it permanent -> Set Resolution ->

Let me know if it works for you, I know it is for 11.10 but it should work for your current version as well.